# Role of CMD["bash"] in Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker

This is the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/fbca80af7960ffcca085d509c20f53ced1697ade/focal/Dockerfile) of Docker Ubuntu official image:

```
FROM scratch
ADD ubuntu-focal-oci-amd64-root.tar.gz /
CMD ["bash"]
```

Can you please help me clarifying the following:

1. What exactly `CMD["bash"]` does? ***I can see no difference by removing it*** (e.g. by adding in my local Dockerfile: `CMD["echo", "hello"]`) when starting a container.
2. The equivalent shell form is `CMD bash` or `CMD exec bash`?
3. If removing that completely, what is the equivalent `docker exec` command line?

I cannot find any reliable answer despite my thorough search...

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: It's (only) useful if you run the container interactively, i.e. with the `-it` options. Then it puts you into a shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0. When you create an image `FROM scratch`, among other things, it has an empty default command, as if you had written

   ```bash
   ENTRYPOINT []
   CMD []
   ```
1. So `CMD` there gives some default command if you `docker run ubuntu`.  Most images will in fact override that `CMD` with something to run the program built into the derived image.
2. Since that `CMD` uses JSON-array syntax, there isn't directly a shell-syntax equivalent of it.  The shell syntax automatically inserts a `sh -c` wrapper around whatever command you give it, so these two would be equivalent

   ```bash
   CMD bash
   CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "bash"]
   ```
3. There would not be an equivalent `docker exec` command.  `docker exec` is a debugging command that's not normally part of the "build and run an image" workflow.  In particular, it does not use the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` from the image at all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, you did not clarify my first query. What CMD["bash"] does in practice? This is still unclear to me

Comment: It does the same thing as `CMD` in any other context: it sets the default command that `docker run ubuntu` executes when it starts the container.  In the case of a base image like this it will usually get overridden in a derived image.

Comment: I am afraid you did not get my point. What this default command (bash) does?

Comment: It's the [GNU Bourne-Again Shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), a largely POSIX-compliant shell that's the standard shell in many Linux distributions.